# Using an Authenticated Proxy server with puppeteer

Tags: proxy, puppeteer

I am trying to use an authenticated proxy server with Puppeteer and hitting a wall.

Proxy service is Crawlera which provides a host `proxy.crawlera.com:8010`

They also provide basic auth username, password is empty.

```
"Error: net::ERR_NO_SUPPORTED_PROXIES",
" at navigate (/Users/me/foo/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:479:37)",
" at <anonymous>"
```

Answer (score 9):

In our case, we set proxy username and password in `--proxy-server` option and it seems to somehow break proxy settings.

What has helped was setting an option:

```
--proxy-server=hostname:port
```

and then provide credentials via:

```
page.authenticate({username: proxyUser, password: proxyPassword)
```

Maybe this will help in your case as well.